# ES query from a golang server to ES returning error while the postman request directly to ES returns the expected results

Tags: elasticsearch, go

This is the request body that I for this endpoint using Postman `localhost:9201/response_v2_862875ee3a88a6d09c95bdbda029ce2b/_search`

```
{
"_source": ["_id"],
"from": 1,
"size": 10,
: {
                                "should": {
                                    "match": {

            }
        }, {
            "range": {
                "_updated_at": {
                    "from": "36163",
                    "include_lower": true,
                    "include_upper": true,
                    "to": null
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
}
```

To this url localhost:9201/rensedbda029ce2b/_search

And I get the results https://gist.gith

But when I make the same request from my server to ES I get an error saying "elastic: Error 400 (Bad Request): Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [START_ARRAY] [type=parsing_exception]"

These are some snippets of my code. I get the query from another util function and use that while making the call to ES.

This is the call to ES `res, err = r.esConn.Search(indexName).e(requestBody.ResponsePageLength).Do(ctx)`

and the query builder function is this, it takes arguments which are extracted from the body of the request to my server and builds a query based on that.

```
func CreateMonitoringPipeline(maxResponseTime string, responseQueries []ResponseQuery, baselineFormId string) *elastic.BoolQuery {
finalQuery := elastic.NewBoolQuery()

    dateRangeMatchQuery := elastic.NewRangeQuery("_updated_at").
        Gte(maxResponseTime)

    finalQuery.Filter(dateRangeMatchQuery)
}

return finalQuery
}
```

I can't figure out why is this happening? my ES is running using the ES binary and my server runs in a docker container.

Completely new to ES and golang so please help.

UPDATE:

This is what I got when I logged my request using `SetTraceLog`

```
| ELASTICPOST /resp8ecf8427e/_search HTTP/1.1
| Host: 172.17.0.1:9201
| User-Agent: elastic/5.0.81 (linux-amd64)
| Transfer-Encoding: chunked
| Accept: application/json
| Content-Type: application/json
| Accept-Encoding: gzip
| 
| 7
| ["_id"]
| 0
```

I can't understand what do the 7 and `["_id"]` mean. Is this my request body that ES received?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are other errors but I think you intended `monitoringAnswersPipeline = append(monitoringAnswersPipeline, esSubQuery)` to go inside the for loop, otherwise it just adds the final esSubQuery rather than all of them.

Comment: Also, if you are using the `olivere/elastic` library which I think you are you can turn on a feature to print the request before it is sent by doing calling `SetTraceLog` when you create the client.  https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#SetTraceLog  This will print out the actual request you are making so you can compare it with the one you are sending in Postman

Comment: @IainDuncan I have added the ES logs to my question, can you take a look please?

Comment: thanks! That had enough information in it to provide an answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for uploading the logs, you are right that the `["_id"]` is the request being sent. The problem is in the request line as `Source([]string{"_id"})` does not set the source field to `["_id"]` as you intended but instead:

> Source allows the user to set the request body manually without using
>   any of the structs and interfaces in Elastic.

https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#SearchService.Source

You want to use `FetchSourceContext` instead:

```
res, err = r.esConn.Search(indexName).From(requestBody.MaxResponseTimestampCount).FetchSourceContext(elastic.NewFetchSourceContect(true). Include("_id")).Query(query).Size(requestBody.ResponsePageLength).Do(ctx)
```

https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#SearchService.FetchSourceContext